# XSD tool to extract error messages

Tags: xml, xsd

I was wondering if there is a tool available which can extract a list of all possible error messages from an XSD?

I have search online and cannot find anything obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSDs don't contain error messages per se.

Generally, if you run a validating parser over an XML document associated with an XSD, you'll receive errors and warnings relating to the validity of the XML against the XSD.

There may be documentation within an XSD.  This or other parts of an XSD might be extracted using XPath as the XSD itself is an XML document.

Finally, if you're looking to determine every possible validation message that could arise across the space of all XML documents for a given XSD, no, there is no such tool.

Comment: That is true, however at it's core an XSD is only a set of rules which will provide data integrity to an XML Doc which is supposed to be validated against it. It is this idea which made me wonder whether there might be a way/an existing tool which looks at this set of rules and provides the parser related error message against every rule. An example would be if node A is set to contain only integers and has a max value set to X, then you would expect error messages relating to those 2 rules. Node A cannot be 'abc' or greater than X.

Comment: At its core, an XSD provides the basis for validity assessment and augmentation of an XML document with a PSVI, but other than curiosity, is there a reason for your request for all possible error messages?  Perhaps we can help with the actual X if this is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  If there's nothing more behind your question than curiosity, the direct answer is as I've said: No, there is no such tool.

Comment: My question arose while writing unit tests for a process which involves validating an XML using an XSD which is provided to me by a 3rd party. I thought it would be pretty great if I could know all possible error messages the parser might come up with so as to write a very comprehensive set of unit tests.

Comment: Your completeness ambition is admirable, but such an approach would be better suited for testing the validating parser itself than an application using the parser.  Focus on testing code that supports the functionality provided by the system.  There are too many ways any non-trivial XML validation can fail, and too many of those are too uninteresting at the application level to warrant their own tests.   In any event, no, there are no tools that will list every possible validation message that could occur for a given XSD.